# Average calculations using AVG() gives wrong result in quicksigth reports

Tags: calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

For a report need to calculate Average initiation time and Average Completion time for a Case by Support team.
Getting time difference in minutes for Initiation time and completion time.
Using avg() funtion in Quicksigth to calcuate average for every client.

Values 
1)211
2)1581
3)1692

Number of records 
- 3

Desired result 
- 1161.33

Result shown
- 1425.25

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA8lo.png)Report in Quicksight

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv6ke.png)Report in Quicksight

Answer (score 1):

Use the avg on the value column option ,don't use the avg function on calculated field to have the global avg

[image]

If you want to have the avg over all the cases, you need to process the avg from all the rows and not on every rows.

The calculated field are applied as an additional column on every row.
Hope that help :)